# Django many-to-one related query with "and" condition

Tags: django, django-models, django-queryset, django-filter

I have the following models struct:

```
class Drive(models.Model):
 car_name = models.CharField(max_length=3,blank=True, null=True,choices=sp.CAR_NAMES ,help_text="The name of the car")
class DataEntity(models.Model):
 parent_drive = models.ForeignKey(Drive,models.CASCADE)
 type = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True,choices=sp.DATA_ENTITY_TYPES, help_text="The Type of the data")
```

And i'm trying to get all of the Drives that have DataEntity.type = 3 **and** DataEntity.type = 4

I tried to use the following:

```
query_set = Q{(AND: ('dataentity__type', 3), ('dataentity__type', 4))}
Drive.objects.filter(query_set).distinct()
```

but i got empty list...
I had a look on the sql statement:

```
SELECT ••• FROM `drive` INNER JOIN `data_entity` ON (`drive`.`id` = `data_entity`.`parent_drive_id`) WHERE (`data_entity`.`type` = 3 AND `data_entity`.`type` = 4)) subquery
```

The Django system put the condition inside the WHERE statement, and it cause the problem (there is no data DataEntity that contain the both types)

How can i make the right queryset in reason to get Drives that contain DataEntity.type = 3 **and** DataEntity.type = 4 ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can try to do this:

```
Drive.objects.filter(dataentity__type__in=[3, 4]).distinct()
```

Comment: I tried your suggestion and i got the **Union** group but i'm looking for the **Intersection** group

The sql statement was:
`SELECT ••• FROM `drive` INNER JOIN `data_entity` ON (`drive`.`id` = `data_entity`.`parent_drive_id`) WHERE (`data_entity`.`type` = 3 OR `data_entity`.`type` = 4)) subquery`

Comment: Still it not solved the problem, it gave me the Drive that contain data_entity.type = 3 **OR** contain data_entity.type = 4 and i'm looking for the **AND** statement

Comment: Actually it works with the following:
`Drive.objects.filter(Q(dataentity__type=3)).filter(Q(dataentity__type=4)).distinct()`

But i'm looking for one Queryset...

Comment: It's give the same result of your first suggestion `(OR: ('dataentity__type', 3), ('dataentity__type', 4))` union of the conditions

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution.
When you used  `Q(dataentity__type=3)&Q(dataentity__type=4)` the ORM system put the AND expression in the "Where" section:

```
SELECT ••• FROM drive` INNER JOIN data_entity ON (drive.id = data_entity.parent_drive_id) WHERE (data_entity.type = 3 AND data_entity.type = 4))
```

and i got 0 results since there is no dataentity that have two types.

But when i used `Drive.objects.filter(Q(dataentity__type=3))&filter(Q(dataentity__type=4)).distinct()`
I got the Drives that have dataentity of type 3 and also dataentity of type 4
The SQL Query:

```
SELECT ••• FROM `drive` INNER JOIN `data_entity` ON (`drive`.`id` = `data_entity`.`parent_drive_id`) LEFT OUTER JOIN `data_entity` T3 ON (`drive`.`id` = T3.`parent_drive_id`) WHERE (`data_entity`.`type` = 3 AND T3.`type` = 4)
```